# Slide Touch and mouse with Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, slider, touch, slideshow

I have this slider that works on touch devices and it also detects mouse movement but the problem is that it detects all the movements that one makes, I would like you to help me by making it only detect when the finger or the mouse slides to the left or to the left. Right and right there you should let scroll down since wanting to see some other different information that is below the slider does not allow scrolling because the slider detects it and when dragging down what it does is move the images, only if you touch a space outside the slider if it drops. I would appreciate a lot if you could help me.

Here I share the complete code

```js
var slidenumber = document.getElementsByClassName('content_inner').length;//how much slide
for(b=0; b<slidenumber; b++){
document.getElementById('buttons').innerHTML += '<span class="button"></span>';//adding buttons by slide number
}
var button = document.querySelectorAll(".button");//get array from buttons
var content = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
button[0].classList.add('active');//adding active class to first button for default view
var a = 0;
for(let i=0; i<button.length; i++){
  button[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    for(let z=0; z<button.length; z++){
      button[z].classList.remove('active')// when click any button delete active class from others
    }
    button[i].classList.add('active');//adding active class clicking button
    a = i;
  content.style.transform = "translateX(calc(-100% * ("+ i +"-1))";
});
} 

button2 = document.querySelectorAll(".slide_buttons_button");//getting next and prew buttons
for(t=0;t<button2.length;t++){
  button2[t].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if(e.target.id == "before_button"){//if button for prew it make variable x-1
    a = a - 1;
    if( a == -1){
      a = slidenumber - 1
    }
    }
    
    if(e.target.id == "after_button"){//if button for next it make variable x+1
    a = a + 1;
    if( a == slidenumber){
      a = 0
    }
    }
    for(let a=0; a < slidenumber; a++){
      button[a].classList.remove('active')
    }
    button[a].classList.add('active');
    content.style.transform = "translateX(calc(-100% * ("+ a +"))";//using variable for change slide
  });
};


//touch sliding
  var posN = 0,
      posZ1 = 0,
        posZ = 0,
      yeni = 0,
      dem = 0,
      mytrans = window.getComputedStyle(content).getPropertyValue('transform'),
      slides = content.getElementsByClassName('content_inner'),
      slidesLength = slides.length,
      slideSize = content.getElementsByClassName('content_inner')[0].offsetWidth;

  // mouse events
  content.onmousedown = dragStart;
  
  // touch events
  content.addEventListener('touchstart', dragStart);
  content.addEventListener('touchend', dragEnd);
  content.addEventListener('touchmove', dragAction);
  

function dragStart (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    //posInitial =  content.offsetLeft;
    posN = 0;
    posZ = 0;
    if (e.type == 'touchstart') {
      posX1 = e.touches[0].clientX;

    } else {
      posX1 = e.clientX;
    }
    
         if (e.type == 'touchstart') {
      posX2 = e.touches[0].clientX;
    } else {
      posX2 = e.clientX;
      document.onmouseup = dragEnd;
      document.onmousemove = dragAction;
    }
    
             if (e.type == 'touchstart') {
      posX3 = e.touches[0].clientX;
    }
    
    else {
      posX3 = e.clientX;
    }
    
  }

  function dragAction (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    
    if (e.type == 'touchmove') {
      posN = e.touches[0].clientX - posX1;
      posX1 = e.touches[0].clientX;
      
    } else {
      posN = e.clientX - posX1;
      posX1 = e.clientX;
    }
      
    if (e.type == 'touchmove') {
      posZ = posX2 - e.touches[0].clientX;
      posX2 = e.touches[0].clientX;
    } else {
      posZ = posX2 - e.clientX;
      posX2 = e.clientX;
    }
      
      var myff = posX2 - posX3;
content.style.transform = "translateX(calc((-100% * ("+ a +")) + ("+ myff +"px)))";
      console.log("calc((-100% * ("+ a +")) + ("+ myff +"px))");

          if(mytrans !== "none"){
      dem = parseInt((mytrans.replace (/,/g, "")).split(" ")[4]);
    }
    
    else{
mytrans = window.getComputedStyle(content).getPropertyValue('transform');
    }
          console.log(myff)

  }

  function dragEnd (e) {
        if(mytrans !== "none"){
      posFinal = parseInt((mytrans.replace (/,/g, "")).split(" ")[4]);
    };
    //console.log(posN)
    if (posN < 0) {
      //console.log("burda knk1");
      content.style.transform = "translateX(calc(-100% * ("+ a +" + 1))";
      a = a + 1;
      if( a == slidenumber){
      a = 0
    }
    } else if (posN > 0) { 
      //console.log("burda knk2");
      content.style.transform = "translateX(calc(-100% * ("+ a +" - 1))";
      a = a - 1;
          if( a == -1){
      a = slidenumber - 1
    }
    }
    
    for(let z=0; z<button.length; z++){
        button[z].classList.remove('active')
      }
      button[a].classList.add('active');
  content.style.transform = "translateX(calc(-100% * ("+ a +")";
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }


function timeout() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        a = a + 1;
        if( a == slidenumber){
            a = 0
        }
        content.style.transform = "translateX(calc(-100% * ("+ a +"))";
        for(let z=0; z<button.length; z++){
        button[z].classList.remove('active')
      }
      button[a].classList.add('active');
        timeout();
    }, 5000)
}
timeout();
```

```css
* {
    width:100%; 
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
 .wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
 .container {
   overflow-x: hidden;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
}
 #buttons {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     top: -1rem;
         position: relative;
}
 #buttons .button {
     width: 0.75rem;
     height: 0.75rem;
     border: 1px solid grey;
     border-radius: 50%;
     margin-right: 0.25rem;
         cursor: pointer;
}
 #buttons .button.active {
     background: green;
}
 .content {
     display: flex;
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     transition: 350ms ease;
}
 .content_inner {
     background: grey;
     flex-shrink: 0;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     width: 100%;
}

 .slide_buttons_button.active {
     background: green;
}
 .content.toggle1 {
     transform: translateX(-100%);
}

@media (orientation:landscape){
.content_inner img{
height: 95vh;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content_inner"> <a href="go:ass"><img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/jqwM0nhOLEFI1HHBabwr80Od3TC.jpg"></div></a>
      <div class="content_inner"><a href="go:eed"><img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/7d6EY00g1c39SGZOoCJ5Py9nNth.jpg"></div></a>
      <div class="content_inner"><img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/6qVF0gnLnbKCgcMfCpCB8GH7B5I.jpg"></div>
      <div class="content_inner"><img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/jqwM0nhOLEFI1HHBabwr80Od3TC.jpg"></div>
      <div class="content_inner"><img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/7d6EY00g1c39SGZOoCJ5Py9nNth.jpg"></div> 
      <div class="content_inner"><img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/jqwM0nhOLEFI1HHBabwr80Od3TC.jpg"></div>
      <div class="content_inner"><img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/7d6EY00g1c39SGZOoCJ5Py9nNth.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="buttons"></div>
    <div class="slide_buttons">
      <div class="slide_buttons_button" id="before_button"></div>
      <div class="slide_buttons_button" id="after_button"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```